# How to set the pipeline for a spider

Tags: python, scrapy

I have a spider that crawls a site.  But in one crawl I need to grab certain data and save it to one database.  In another, grab different data and put it somewhere else.

Right now pass a `target` parameter when I create the spider to manage which options it will use.  The init method then tweaks the search parameters.

Is there a way I can have the spider set its pipeline in the init?  Or something in the crawl script that would do it?

At the moment, I start the crawl like this:

```
process = CrawlerProcess(get_project_settings())
process.crawl('my_spider', target='target_one')
process.start()
```

I have a separate script for whichever target I intend to run.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Changing `settings` in Spider, this will override settings mentioned in `settings.py`

```
class MySpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "My_spider"

    custom_settings = {
        'DOWNLOADER_MIDDLEWARES': {
            'my_scraper.middlewarees.MyMiddleware': 300,
        },
        'ITEM_PIPELINES': {
                'my_scraper.pipelines.MyPipeline': 300,
        }
    }
```

Or if you are using `CrawlerProcess`

```
from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerProcess
from scrapy.utils.project import get_project_settings
from testspiders.spiders.followall import FollowAllSpider 

FollowAllSpider.custom_settings={'ITEM_PIPELINES': {'my_scraper.pipelines.MyPipeline': 300}}

process = CrawlerProcess(get_project_settings())

# 'followall' is the name of one of the spiders of the project.
process.crawl('testspider', domain='scrapinghub.com')
process.start() # the script will block here until the crawling is finished
```